# why non-zero vectors required for independence of vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

A sequence of vectors $v_1, v_2, \cdots, v_n$ are independent when the only combination that produces a $\mathbf{0}$ vector is $0\cdot v_1+0\cdot v_2+\cdots+0\cdot v_n$ (as per the textbook definition (Gilbert Strang Linear Algebra)).

In this book, it is also mentioned that when one the $v_i$'s is a zero vector, then independence has no chance.

Why is it so?

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that $v_1$ is the zero vector.  Then
$$
1\cdot v_1 + 0 \cdot v_2+ \cdots + 0\cdot v_n = \mathbf{0}.
$$
So, you've created the zero vector with one of the scalars (namely, the first one) not being zero.  Thus this set of vectors is not independent.